# org-mode: How to change cursor type for variable-pitch mode?

Tags: cursor, variable-pitch

I have the following block of lisp codes in my .emacs config to enable variable-pitch mode for Org-mode. It is working fine however the cursor has changed from the default block to a thin line. Could someone please advise how or what I can add into the function below to change cursor-type back to box?

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(fixed-pitch ((t (:height 130 :family "Consolas"))))
 '(org-code ((t (:foreground "DarkOrange1"))))
 '(variable-pitch ((t (:height 130 :family "Helvetica Neue LT Std")))))

;; Set variable-pitch for org buffer, except org-table/code/block
(defun set-buffer-variable-pitch ()
  (interactive)
  (variable-pitch-mode t)
  (setq cursor-type 'box)
  (setq line-spacing 3)
   (set-face-attribute 'org-table nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
   (set-face-attribute 'org-code nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
   (set-face-attribute 'org-block nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
   (set-face-attribute 'org-block-background nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
  )
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'set-buffer-variable-pitch)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reducing your init file just to the snippet above? Does the problem still persist?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 i haven’t tried that but I have tried just commenting out the add-hook command and the cursor came back to normal, or just enabling fixed-pitch mode in the buffer would do the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried moving the point on top of characters that you've already typed? I assume `variable-pitch` mode still tries to draw a block that's 1 character wide, which will vary depending on the character.

Comment: You are right, when the cursor is on top of any character it goes back to being a box. Do you know if there is anything I could try to set the cursor-type to a box always?

Comment: Thechnically it's a block as big as one character, the problem being that character sizes vary. A fixed size block could get confusing when you put it onto a string of something like narrow characters. It could even be mistaken for a region marking a couple of characters.